# How can I split a long string and insert into a mysql databse using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, split

I have a long string containing the following strings :-

```
1)serviceName
2)categoryName
3)itemName
4)itemRate
5)itemQuantity
6)itemTotal
```

Following is the string I want to split and insert into the above 6 columns:-

```
Laundry, men, shirt, 60, 3, 180, Laundry, men, T-shirt, 50, 2, 100, Laundry, men, jeans/Trousers, 60, 2, 120, Laundry, women, blouse, 50, 2, 100, Laundry, women, dress, 120, 2, 240, Laundry, women, long dress, 190, 2, 380, Laundry, women, saree, 160, 1, 160, Laundry, household, bedspread single, 90, 2, 180, Laundry, household, bedspread double, 140, 2, 280, Laundry, household, bedsheet single, 60, 2, 120, Laundry, household, bedsheet double, 90, 2, 180
```

How can I split this string and insert into it's respective columns?
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: where does the string come from? (trying to find the X of the Y-Problem)

Comment: Thank you @GurwinderSingh I have no control over the source. Sorry.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This looks very straightforward...

Comment: @EdCottrell I tried splitting the string and converting it into an array but I am not getting a proper array.I tried this $myArray = explode(',', $myString);
print_r($myArray);

Comment: You can always count on StackOverflow to spoonfeed complete code for low-hanging-fruit, zero-effort-beforehand questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following code

```
<?php
$str = "Laundry, men, shirt, 60, 3, 180, Laundry, men, T-shirt, 50, 2, 100, Laundry, men, jeans/Trousers, 60, 2, 120, Laundry, women, blouse, 50, 2, 100, Laundry, women, dress, 120, 2, 240, Laundry, women, long dress, 190, 2, 380, Laundry, women, saree, 160, 1, 160, Laundry, household, bedspread single, 90, 2, 180, Laundry, household, bedspread double, 140, 2, 280, Laundry, household, bedsheet single, 60, 2, 120, Laundry, household, bedsheet double, 90, 2, 180";
$array = explode(",",$str);
$newarray = array();
$temp = "";
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($array);$i++)
{
     if(($i+1)%6==0)
     {
           $temp .= $array[$i];
           array_push($newarray,$temp);
           $temp = "";
     }else{
           $temp .= $array[$i].","; 
     }

}
print_r($newarray);
?>
```

Comment: my apology i missed one bracket in condition check out edited version

Comment: Welcome @AndroidNewBee comments like this motivates us to share the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regex. As long as your data always has the above format, the following code will split your data into an array of arrays, with appropriate key names:

```
<?php

$data = "Laundry, men, shirt, 60, 3, 180, Laundry, men, T-shirt, 50, 2, 100, Laundry, men, jeans/Trousers, 60, 2, 120, Laundry, women, blouse, 50, 2, 100, Laundry, women, dress, 120, 2, 240, Laundry, women, long dress, 190, 2, 380, Laundry, women, saree, 160, 1, 160, Laundry, household, bedspread single, 90, 2, 180, Laundry, household, bedspread double, 140, 2, 280, Laundry, household, bedsheet single, 60, 2, 120, Laundry, household, bedsheet double, 90, 2, 180";

$regex = '/(?P<serviceName>[^,]+),\s*(?P<categoryName>[^,]+),\s*(?P<itemName>[^,]+),\s*(?P<itemRate>[^,]+),\s*(?P<itemQuantity>[^,]+),\s*(?P<itemTotal>[^,]+)(?:,\s*|$)/';

preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laundry, men, shirt, 60, 3, 180, 
            [serviceName] => Laundry
            [1] => Laundry
            [categoryName] => men
            [2] => men
            [itemName] => shirt
            [3] => shirt
            [itemRate] => 60
            [4] => 60
            [itemQuantity] => 3
            [5] => 3
            [itemTotal] => 180
            [6] => 180
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laundry, men, T-shirt, 50, 2, 100, 
            [serviceName] => Laundry
            [1] => Laundry
            [categoryName] => men
            [2] => men
            [itemName] => T-shirt
            [3] => T-shirt
            [itemRate] => 50
            [4] => 50
            [itemQuantity] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [itemTotal] => 100
            [6] => 100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laundry, men, jeans/Trousers, 60, 2, 120, 
            [serviceName] => Laundry
            [1] => Laundry
            [categoryName] => men
            [2] => men
            [itemName] => jeans/Trousers
            [3] => jeans/Trousers
            [itemRate] => 60
            [4] => 60
            [itemQuantity] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [itemTotal] => 120
            [6] => 120
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laundry, women, blouse, 50, 2, 100, 
            [serviceName] => Laundry
            [1] => Laundry
            [categoryName] => women
            [2] => women
            [itemName] => blouse
            [3] => blouse
            [itemRate] => 50
            [4] => 50
            [itemQuantity] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [itemTotal] => 100
            [6] => 100
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laundry, women, dress, 120, 2, 240, 
            [serviceName] => Laundry
            [1] => Laundry
            [categoryName] => women
            [2] => women
            [itemName] => dress
            [3] => dress
            [itemRate] => 120
            [4] => 120
            [itemQuantity] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [itemTotal] => 240
            [6] => 240
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laundry, women, long dress, 190, 2, 380, 
            [serviceName] => Laundry
            [1] => Laundry
            [categoryName] => women
            [2] => women
            [itemName] => long dress
            [3] => long dress
            [itemRate] => 190
            [4] => 190
            [itemQuantity] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [itemTotal] => 380
            [6] => 380
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laundry, women, saree, 160, 1, 160, 
            [serviceName] => Laundry
            [1] => Laundry
            [categoryName] => women
            [2] => women
            [itemName] => saree
            [3] => saree
            [itemRate] => 160
            [4] => 160
            [itemQuantity] => 1
            [5] => 1
            [itemTotal] => 160
            [6] => 160
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laundry, household, bedspread single, 90, 2, 180, 
            [serviceName] => Laundry
            [1] => Laundry
            [categoryName] => household
            [2] => household
            [itemName] => bedspread single
            [3] => bedspread single
            [itemRate] => 90
            [4] => 90
            [itemQuantity] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [itemTotal] => 180
            [6] => 180
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laundry, household, bedspread double, 140, 2, 280, 
            [serviceName] => Laundry
            [1] => Laundry
            [categoryName] => household
            [2] => household
            [itemName] => bedspread double
            [3] => bedspread double
            [itemRate] => 140
            [4] => 140
            [itemQuantity] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [itemTotal] => 280
            [6] => 280
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laundry, household, bedsheet single, 60, 2, 120, 
            [serviceName] => Laundry
            [1] => Laundry
            [categoryName] => household
            [2] => household
            [itemName] => bedsheet single
            [3] => bedsheet single
            [itemRate] => 60
            [4] => 60
            [itemQuantity] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [itemTotal] => 120
            [6] => 120
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => Laundry, household, bedsheet double, 90, 2, 180
            [serviceName] => Laundry
            [1] => Laundry
            [categoryName] => household
            [2] => household
            [itemName] => bedsheet double
            [3] => bedsheet double
            [itemRate] => 90
            [4] => 90
            [itemQuantity] => 2
            [5] => 2
            [itemTotal] => 180
            [6] => 180
        )

)
```

Here's a [demo](https://3v4l.org/NkAtP). This uses the magic of [named subpatterns](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#example-5381) (the `(?P<foo>...)` syntax).